# MS Access - How to add incremental values to groups in table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a huge table of items in MS Access 2007 to appear on product pages, which looks similar to this:

```
ID   | GroupID | ItemName       | Sort | Type

225  | 5       | Specifications | 0    | Text
226  | 5       | Option-Red     | 0    | Product
227  | 5       | Option-Blue    | 0    | Product
228  | 7       | Specifications | 0    | Text
229  | 7       | Option-Green   | 0    | Product
230  | 7       | Option-Orange  | 0    | Product
231  | 7       | Option-Pink    | 0    | Product
232  | 7       | Option-Black   | 0    | Product
```

First item in each group is the specification item, and then a list of products.

They need to have their 'sort' sequence added per-group so that the system being used will put them in their correct order, like this:

```
ID   | GroupID | ItemName       | Sort | Type

225  | 5       | Specifications | 0    | Text
226  | 5       | Option-Red     | 1    | Product
227  | 5       | Option-Blue    | 2    | Product
228  | 7       | Specifications | 0    | Text
229  | 7       | Option-Green   | 1    | Product
230  | 7       | Option-Orange  | 2    | Product
231  | 7       | Option-Pink    | 3    | Product
232  | 7       | Option-Black   | 4    | Product
```

But I can't seem to create a query in access that will actually work to do it. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
select x.id, x.group_id, x.itemname, count(y.id) as sort, x.type
  from tbl x
  left outer join tbl y
    on x.group_id = y.group_id
   and y.id < x.id
 group by x.id, x.group_id, x.itemname, x.type
```

See fiddle at:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc4e8/3/0

I know that I used mysql in that fiddle but I am not using any syntax not supported by Access, I don't believe. The only thing you might have to do is enclose the on clause in () , I forget how the on clause works with Access but know it is bizarre.

Comment: Worked flawlessly.  Thank you! Seems so obvious now but I had serious brain-fade over it..

Comment: No problem. It is a 'trick' per se. It counts the number of records with a lower id value than the current value. Normally you would user an analytic function, like row_number() over, but that is not supported by access.

Comment: Yeah my next step was to export it and use real SQL instead but really needed to do it in Access because part of the idea of what im doing is to save the queries to the mdb for use by others in the future.. Cannot stand Access, and think I'd still be here now trying to sort this.. So I cannot thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

Updated for comment:
You can use:

```
 Select * from (
 Select * from yourTableName ORDER BY yourTableName.Sort)
 ORDER BY yourTableName.GroupID
```

When you create simple query, go to the SQL mode and insert the code.

Comment: Thanks for your input Makketronix, I know how to group results but my problem is adding the sort order to them all.. It's not as simple as applying 0-15999 on my group of 16,000 items, because they must be sequential within their own group, ie if there are 8 items in a group, 0-7 must be applied to them in order of their unique ID's, then if the next group has 4 items, they must be 0-3 respectively, not 8-11.. Cheers!