# Access 2013 Item Numbers

Tags: ms-access

I would like to assign an item number to each VT count by Welder/Insp and add another column to assign a number to the item numbers in increments of 20. How do I add this to my SQL to achieve this?  I am attaching a copy of the worksheet so you have a better understanding of what I am trying to arrive at.

```
TRANSFORM Count([Weld Log].Activity) AS CountOfActivity
SELECT [Weld Log].[Welder/Insp], [Weld Log].[Spool #], [Weld Log].[Weld #], [Weld Log].WPS, [Weld Log].Type, [Weld Log].Date, [Weld Log].[Pass or Fail], [Weld Log].Comment, Count([Weld Log].Activity) AS [Total Of Activity]
FROM [Weld Log]
WHERE ((([Weld Log].Type)="BUTTWELD") AND ((([Weld Log].[Pass or Fail])="PASS" Or ([Weld Log].[Pass or Fail])="Fail") And (([Weld Log].[Pass or Fail])="Pass" Or ([Weld Log].[Pass or Fail])="Fail")) AND (([Weld Log].NDE)=("VT")))
GROUP BY [Weld Log].[Welder/Insp], [Weld Log].[Spool #], [Weld Log].[Weld #], [Weld Log].WPS, [Weld Log].NDE, [Weld Log].Type, [Weld Log].Date, [Weld Log].[Pass or Fail], [Weld Log].Comment, [Weld Log].NDE
PIVOT [Weld Log].NDE;
```

[Query Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuOzQ.jpg)

Comment: How is your question about worksheets related to MS Access? If you data resides in an Access database und you use that query for a QueryTable, where are the CountOfActivity and NDE columns? Why using the Pass/Fail criterion twice? Why pivoting at all? When talking about numbering your data and "start over upon change", you also must define a sort order. Why should the first lot contain only 20 items and all others 21? Since MS Acces does not know Window Functions and can't easily detect a change in the first column, you will have to use VBA to fill a table with your desired result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access - How to add incremental values to groups in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853620/ms-access-how-to-add-incremental-values-to-groups-in-table). Or use textbox RunningSum property in report design.